# Jquery Form submit function not triggering and debugging not triggered

Tags: jquery

I've been struggling to figure out what I broke over time on an old ajax request to simply fetch a result into a div instead of going to the page on form submit.  Jquery $ is initialized but this function will not trigger, even added an alert on document ready that does not trigger?

```js
// this is the id of the form
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert("ready");
      $("#rewardsRoll").submit(function(e) {
          alert("roll");
          var form = $(this);
          var url = form.attr('action');

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
              $('#RewardsDiceDiv').html(data);
            }
          });
          return false;
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="RewardsDiceDiv">
  <div style="min-height:50px;text-align:center">
    <form id="rewardsRoll" method="post" action="https://www.allfreechips.com/phpBB2/../dicerewards.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="tttt" />
      <input type="hidden" name="s" value="" />
      <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Use one of your 9958 AFC Rewards"></form>
  </div>
  <div class="dice-container">
    <div class="dice-item">
      // show dice...
    </div>
```

Comment: You haven't closed all your braces. Check the error thrown in browser dev tools console (F12)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#rewardsRoll").submit(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              alert("roll");
              var form = $(this);
              var url = form.attr('action');
              $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: url,
                     data: form.serialize(),
                     success: function(data) {
                       $( '#RewardsDiceDiv' ).html( data );
                     }
             });
             return false;
}
```

Comment: This is close to my orig code without the return false, I then added the doc readsy to see if that would trigger but this as well as old code does not stop execution of the form submit still.  Very odd, ID is unique, Jquery is initialized

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this worked for a year but the fact the javascript was before the form it should have never worked, all working now with script after form.